# How to replace the existing metatag using the backend to insure a thumbnail image gets fetched when we share on social media?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-head

How to replace the existing metatag using the backend to insure a thumbnail image gets fetched when we share on social media?

```
function theme_a_header_metadata() {

  global $post;

  $image = \wpplugin\blogwidget\getBlogImage($post);

?>

  <meta property="og:image" content="<?= getLocalImage($image, '1344x') ?>" />

<?php

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_a_header_metadata' );
```

So I have this function, but the issue is that there's already a meta property with the property value of "og:image", so how do I replace the meta tag? I need to use the backend, and I don't want to install any plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)

`add_action` currently supports 4 parameters: `string $hook_name, callable $callback, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1`

Try adjusting the 3rd parameter "priority" to add the action later than any existing actions (which may have been created by plugins or themes).